# Discord Python - Multiple Prefixes

Tags: discord, discord.py

Is it possible to have multiple prefixes at once?
Example:
@discordbot help
;help (custom prefixes)
and in dms
\help
(I Got a working prefix changer and loader)

If there is, please show me a example or fix my broken code

the code:

```
import discord
import json

from discord import Embed
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import when_mentioned

def get_prefix(client, message):

    guild = message.guild

    if guild:

        with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
            prefixes = json.load(f)

        return prefixes[str(int(message.guild.id))]

    elif not guild:
        return ','

    else:
        return when_mentioned(client, message)

client = commands.client(command_prefix=get_prefix)

@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)

    prefixes[str(int(guild.id))] = '//'

    with open('prefixes.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)

@client.event
async def on_guild_remove(guild):
    with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)

    prefixes.pop(str(int(guild.id)))

    with open('prefixes.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)

@client.command()
async def prefix(ctx, *, prefix):
    with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)

    prefixes[str(int(ctx.guild.id))] = prefix

    with open('prefixes.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)

@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('pong')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('ready')

client.run(token)
```

if not, please show me an example, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can just make it like

```
prefixes = ";", "/" 
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefixes)
```